# How to raise or decrease a display number variable in AS3 with a condition?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, numbers, conditional-statements

I've got, in my Toolbar.as class,  a simple variable (4-digit number) displayed in a dynamic text box, like that :

```
var number = 9999; 
useText.text = String(number); 
trace(number);
```

In my puzzle class I have a condition and I would like to decrease the number if it's true. 
How can I do that ?

For exemple, I've got, in my Puzzle.as class :

```
if (inv.containsItem("rock")) {
    toolbar.useText.text = "String(number)" - 100;
    }
```

But it doesn't work (I know that I have to change the "String(number)" - 100 but what should I put ?

Thx !!!

Comment: Are you trying to do `String(number - 100)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are attempting to do: `String(number - 100);`

The is called a wrapper or casting, you are casting the number variable with the operation of - 100 to a `String`.

If you want to grab the current text in your field and use that:

```
useText.text = String( Number( useText.text ) - 100 );
```

This casts the current text to a `Number`, subtracts 100, then casts it back to a `String`

Comment: But what do I set as a variable for "number". Cause when I write toolbar.useText.text = String(number - 100); I've got to set the variable of "number".

Comment: The number is 9999 at the begning of the game. But I don't want the function to do "9999 - 100" but "number in the useText - 100"

Comment: Ok I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the value of toolbar.useText.text, parse it to int, subtract 100 and assign to toolbar.useText.text.

Comment: You can do the same for a raising.