# Call a function if String number is inferior to 0?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got this code in my Toolbar.as :

```
var money = 9999; 
argent.text = String(money); 
trace(money);
```

How do I do to say

```
if (money < 0){
callFunction(); 
}
```

?

Thank you very much for your answers

---

**EDIT**

I've tried everything.

Here's what I did :

```
var money:int = 9999; 

argent.text = money.toString();
trace(money);
stageRef.addEventListener("checkingMoney", checkMoney, false, 0, true);
```

I've add the EventListner in order to check the money (as nothing was triggering the condition if money<0 before).

And then :

```
public function checkMoney(event):void{
             var money;
            trace("checking");
        if (parseInt(money) < 0){
    trace("dangerous");  
}
}
```

So the function is well triggered (the trace "checking" is on), but even the number is under 0 (-4600), the trace "dangerous" do NOT appear..
I don't understand.

Comment: What type is `money` variable?

Comment: "argent" is a dynamic text. I've followed these tips for the code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339052/how-to-raise-or-decrease-a-display-number-variable-in-as3-with-a-condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't usually do this, but I'm posting a second answer because your edit is drastically different than what you originally posted. For future reference, please post the *entire* code that is relevant. You seemed to have missed some context originally and forced us to solve the wrong problem (don't get me wrong, it still needed to be fixed but it was not the issue at hand)

So what you are seeing is a scope issue. Basically, an object declared in an object (be it a `Class`, `Function`, loop, or conditional) is only available within that object and within child objects. Additionally, **all** objects declared in the top-level scope of a class **must** have an access modifier (`public`, `private`, `internal`, `protected`, etc).

So let's assume this class structure:

```
public class ClassName {
    public function ClassName();
    public function checkMoney();
}
```

An object declared in the constructor (`ClassName()`) is not available in `checkMoney()`. So you need to do one of two things:

Declare the object in top-level scope:

```
public class ClassName {
    private var money:int;
    public function ClassName(){
         money = 9999;
         checkMoney()
    }
    public function checkMoney() {
         // you now have access to money
    }
}
```

or pass the object into the function:

```
public class ClassName {
    public function ClassName(){
         var money:int = 9999;
         checkMoney(money);
    }
    public function checkMoney(value:Number) {
         // check "value" here. Note that Numbers and Strings are NOT passed be reference, so changing the value will NOT change the original variable
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my edit. I'll post the entire code next time. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on how datatyping works. It works similarly in all OOP-based languages, so an AS3-specific article really isn't necessary. Avoid anything regarding PHP datatypes, though.

For what you have posted, though, you have done a few things incorrectly.

First off, every object (whether it be a variable, function, or class), **should always** have the datatype declared. You can get away with not doing it, but your app will run slightly faster if you do and there is less chance of compiler warnings.

So

```
var money = 9999;
```

should be

```
var money:int = 9999; // could also use Number (AS3's float) or uint
```

You should avoid hard-casts such as `String(money)`, as well. This can be slow and can cause errors. For casting a `Number` to a `String`, you should always use `Number.toString()`, as that is its intended purpose and I believe it is optimized whereas other cast types are not.

`if (money < 0)` is actually correct. It may have been throwing IDE warnings because you didn't set the type of `money`. If you need to compare a numeric `String` value, you need to cast it back to a number using `Number(var)`. Note that casting a `String` to `Number` is one of the few times you want to use a hard cast `DataType(object)` instead of a soft cast (`object as DataType`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the problem.

1st of all `money` variable is missing a type.

If money is `int` here than:

```
var money:int = 9999; 
argent.text = money.toString();
trace(money);

if (money < 0){
    callFunction(); 
}
```

and that should work.

If for some reason money is `String` in here than:
    var money:String = "9999"; 
    argent.text = money;
    trace(money);

```
if (Number(money) < 0){
    callFunction(); 
}
```

Comment: or:
`if (parseInt(money) < 0){`

Comment: Don't understand why it is not working. I've tried everything that you guys said. I'm editing my post.

Comment: Hm, but in function `checkMoney` you are declaring new `money` variable but not setting it. By default it's 0 (which is not < 0) and that's why you can't see "dangerous" trace.
You need to pass this variable or if it's in the same class use same variable instead of creating new one in each function.

Comment: I've tried var money:int = 9999, not working. I've tried to put nothing but it says "money" is undefined. Nothing's working.